# How to expose NodePort to internet on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

How can I expose service of type `NodePort` to internet **without** using type `LoadBalancer`? Every resource I have found was doing it by using load balancer. But I don't want load balancing its expensive and unnecessary for my use case because I am running one instance of `postgres` image which is mounting to persistent disk and I would like to be able to connect to my database from my PC using pgAdmin. If it is possible could you please provide bit more detailed answer as I am new to Kubernetes, GCE and networking.

Just for the record and bit more context I have deployment running 3 replicas of my API server to which I am connecting through load balancer with set loadBalancerIP and another deployment which is running one instance of postgres with NodePort service through which my API servers are communicating with my db. And my problem is that maintaining the db without public access is hard.

Comment: if you always want to have exactly 1 replica of your postgres, then there's actually little to none added value from running it on a kubernetes cluster: you can as well run it directly on a VM with a public IP.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

using `NodePort` as Service type works straight away e.g. like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: http
    - port: 443
      nodePort: 30443
      name: https
  selector:
    name: nginx
```

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport).
The drawback of using `NodePort` is that you've to take care of integrating with your providers firewall by yourself. A starting port for that can also be found in the [Configuring Your Cloud Provider's Firewalls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services-firewalls/#google-compute-engine) section of the official documentation.

For GCE opening up the above for publicly on all nodes could look like:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create myservice --allow tcp:30080,tcp:30443
```

Once this is in place your services should be accessable through any of the public IPs of your nodes. You'll find them with:

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

Comment: How can I find out what IP to use for connection string? Can I use some predefined one from Networking > External IP addresses in GCE? Or I get one automatically somehow?

Comment: I can't get it to work. I am doing it exactly as you have told me but none of the 3 ips I get when running `gcloud compute instances list` is responding and I am not forgeting to use `30080` port. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I tested it before I described the steps, make sure to check whether containers and pods run and that the selector in the service matches the pod labels.

Comment: Had the same problem, finally figured it out after several hours -wasted- of learning: my Service `selector` contained a wrong old Deployment name (created with `kubectl expose deployment wrong-old-value`, so it looked like it did something while it actually filtered out my new deployment. Check your `selector` guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can run kubectl in a terminal window (command or power shell in windows) to port forward the postgresql deployment to your localhost.

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/my-pg-deployment 5432:5432
```

While this command is running (it runs in the foreground) you can use pgAdmin to point to localhost:5432 to access your pod on the gke. Simply close the terminal once you are done using the pgadmin.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of improved **security**: if in doubt about exposing a service like a database to the public internet, you might like the idea of hiding it behind a simple linux VM called jump host, also called [bastion host in the official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#bastion) which is recommended. This way your database instance will continue being open towards the internal network. You then can remove the external IP address so that it stops being exposed to the internet.

**The high level concept:**

```
public internet <- SSH:22 -> bastion host <- db:5432 -> database service
```

After setting up your ssh connection and establishing connection, you could reach out to the database by forwarding the database port (see example below).

### The Procedure Overview

### Create the GCE VM

Specific requirements:

1. Pick the image of a Linux distribution you are familiar with
2. VM Connectivity to internet: Attach a public IP to the VM (you can do this during or after the installation)
3. Security: Go to Firewall rules and add a new rule opening port 22 at *internal* VM IP. Restrict the incoming connections to your home public IP
4. Go to your local machine, from which you would connect, and setup the connection like in the following example below.

### SSH Connect to the bastion host VM

**An example setup for your ssh connection**, located at $HOME/.ssh/config (if this file called config doesn't exist, just create it):

```
Host bastion-host-vm
     Hostname external-vm-ip
     User root
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
     LocalForward 5432 internal-vm-ip:5432
```

Now you are ready for connecting from your local machine terminal with this command:

```
ssh bastion-host-vm
```

Once connected, you could now pick your favorite database client and connect to localhost:5432 (which is the forwarded port through the ssh connection from the remote database instance, which is behind the ssh host).

**CAUTION:** The port forwarding is only function as long as the ssh connection is established. If you disconnect or close the terminal window the ssh connection will close, and so the database port forwarding as well. So keep the terminal open and connection to your bastion host established as long as you are using the database connection.

### Pro tipp for cost saving on the GCE VM

you could use the free tier offer for creating the bastion host VM which means increased protection for free.
Search for "Compute Engine" [in the official table.](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#free-tier-usage-limits)

You could [check this thread for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63188016/8296094) on GCE free limits.